# Transform a list of lists into a list of numbers based on uniqueness

Tags: python

So let us say that we have a 2 dimensional list of numbers:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5]]
```

And I want to change each sub-list to a number, but let similar lists have the same number.
So the given example would become:

```
[1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: I don't understand what this question is even asking for. How did you arrive at 1,2,1,3? What's the conversion process from a list to a number?

Comment: The question is clear enough.  Read it again.  Each new sub-list gets assigned the next higher number.  Each previously seen sub-list uses the previously assigned number.

Comment: @MattDMo I only have ideas but I havent tried any so far. They seem kind of inefficient.

Comment: There's an easy way to do this, but you need to make the sub-lists hashable by converting them to tuples.  Then just keep a dict of the tuples.  When you encounter a new one, assign a new number.  If it's already in the dict, get the number from the dict.

Comment: By this, we can use the ```.index()``` method?

Comment: @Sujay I would consider that unacceptable.  It's O(n**2).  The time complexity should be linear in the length of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5]]

from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

m = defaultdict(partial(next, count()))
[m[tuple(e)]+1 for e in l]

Out[24]: [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: The former is O(N^2); OP wants an efficient solution and this can easily be linear. The second one looks fine though - I don't know how that module works, but using a dict and storing the occurence counter each time looks to be linear.

Comment: Does anyone know what the efficiency of the second solution? I am not familiar with the imported modules. Is this really linear?

Comment: @bobthesnob It's linear.  It makes heavy use of libraries, and as a result the code is very compact, but it's efficient.  You could do the same thing without the libraries.  It would take a few more lines, but the efficiency would be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work?

```
def get_unique_list(list_of_lists):
    return_list = []
    unique_lists = []

    for list in list_of_lists:
        if list not in unique_lists:
            unique_lists.append(list)
        return_list.append(unique_lists.index(list)+1)

    return return_list

print(get_unique_list([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5]]))
```

Comment: You shadowed the ```list``` function

Comment: This is O(N^2).

Comment: This is bad code.  It's an O(n**2) solution to a linear problem.  Learn to use hashing.  Remember, OP requested an *efficient* solution, which this is not.  So, to answer your question, no, this would not work, it's too slow.